# I have created a Adobe muse website and Im trying to upload it to WordPress and im getting errors

Tags: wordpress, adobe, muse

So I have created a website in Muse and I'm trying to upload it to my Website Via Word Press, however; I'm getting issues I think is to do with a PHP and HTML clash.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: what issues are you having? you have to describe your issues in detail, and what have you tried so far to solve them, so that we can help you. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can not upload your adobe muse site in Wordpress installation. Muse created files are HTML, CSS, JS etc and Wordpress works with databases and PHP.

I assume you want to use adobe muse created pages in Wordpress as template. This is not a great idea unless you know how to create Wordpress templates and how to code with HTML, CSS, PHP etc.

Regards
CD